# How to transfer save data from a PSP go to a PSP 300?

Tags: psp

I want to transfer my save data from my PSP go to my other PSP.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's totally possible, you just have to:

- connect your PSP Go to your PC with an USB cable
- access the root of your PSP Go internal memory data (connecting your PSP to your PC throught USB cable is like connecting an USB key, so your PSP storage is normally listed in file explorer)
- open the `PSP` folder
- copy the `SAVEDATA` folder somewhere in your PC
- then, connect your PSP 3000 to your PC
- and simply copy-paste your `SAVEDATA` folder into its `PSP` directory
- that's all! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but at this point in time you'll probably need to buy PC card readers to pull it off. In the past you could just use Media Manager on your PC, link the PSP Go to your PC and backup the save data, then hook up your PSP and restore the save data. Since Media Manager is no longer supported, your next best bet is to buy both an M2 adapter and a DUO adapter and copy the SAVEDATA folder for the games to a PC from one card. Then switch cards and copy it to the same folder on the other card.

Comment: Or you could just simply connect the PSP to the computer? Saves are simply stored in a directory.